Understanding acquire-release example from book C++ concurrency in action
Could you, please, explain why assert can fire? I cannot understand the explanation below. Both if(y.load... and if(x.load... use std::memory_order_acquire. Is not this enough? In the book it's written that we need seq_cst for assert not to fire. How does seq_cst improve here?
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>

std::atomic<bool> x,y;
std::atomic<int> z;

void write_x()
{
 x.store(true,std::memory_order_release);
}

void write_y()
{
 y.store(true,std::memory_order_release);
}

void read_x_then_y()
{
 while(!x.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
 if(y.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) 
  ++z;
}

void read_y_then_x()
{
 while(!y.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
 if(x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) 
  ++z;
}
int main()
{
 x=false;
 y=false;
 z=0;

 std::thread a(write_x);
 std::thread b(write_y);
 std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
 std::thread d(read_y_then_x);

 a.join();
 b.join();
 c.join();
 d.join();

 assert(z.load()!=0); 
}


In this case the assert  can fire (like in the relaxed-ordering case), because it’s possible for both the load of x  and the load of y to read false. x and y are written by different threads, so the ordering from the release to the acquire in each case has no
effect on the operations in the other threads.


think that the release sequence only establishes synchronization between two threads,  (and any other thread participating in the release sequence by doing a read-modify-write), in other words their caches will be in sync, then read_x_then_y will be synchronized with write_x and then read_y_then_x will be synchronized with write_y, there is no synchronization between the different groups ,seq_cst is used to enforce a single global ordering among all atomics or they must participate in the release sequence

Because of release/require, the third thread can see updates on x and on y, but the relative order is not guarantied by release/require. It can be x update then a later y update. Same for the fourth thread which can see y update then x update. At the end z can be 0, 1 or 2.

In physical terms it's not specified how many CPUs, Cores or levels of memory cache exist or are shared between the threads. It may be that thread c executes somewhere 'near' a and d somewhere near b. As mentioned by the comments and answers ensuring sequentially consistent ordering in which all threads observe the same order has an overhead and the choice of memory ordering in the example explicitly indicates that is not required.

@AhmedAEK, but is not y.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) synchronize read_x_then_y with write_y (I mean, after its sync with write_x)?

Sorry cannot get it. Acquire memory order should get synchronized first c with a and then c with b

@JenyaKh the question here is whether both c and d will see the same order of modification of both a and b, in other words if a and b have a well-defined order that both c and d will agree on, the answer is NO, thread c can see a then b while thread d can see b then a , thus the assertion will trigger, whether it happens or not is a race, and the only thing that will make the trigger not happen is there being a well defined order in which a and b happen that other threads can agree on, there is none without seq_cst, because b doesn't participate in the release sequence of a and vice versa.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

memory_order_seq_cst A load operation with this memory order performs an acquire operation, a store performs a release operation, and read-modify-write performs both an acquire operation and a release operation, plus a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications in the same order (see Sequentially-consistent ordering below).

Without memory_order_seq_cst different threads can see atomic operations happen in different orders. It's possible for read_x_then_y to see:
x = true;
y = true; 

Whilst read_y_then_x could see:
y = true;
x = true; 

In this case if both threads then test their second variable between the two writes neither will write z.
The atomic writes are likely happening on different CPU cores, the cores then have to communicate with each other about the writes, without memory_order_seq_cst they won't necessarily bother going to the extra effort of making sure that all cores have the same view of the order in which the writes occurred.
